# Make dropdown list reference 2 sql columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp-classic

There are 2 columns, one with name and the other with email addresses. I want to be able to display the names from the name's column in a dropdown but user the email in the next column when the form is submitted on my asp page.

```
public void FillAssignedToDropdownOnsite()
{
    SqlConnection con = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["onsite_db"].ConnectionString);
    string query = "SELECT Name, EmailAddress FROM OnsiteData ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    adpt.Fill(dt);
    cmd.Connection.Close();

    lstAssignedTo.DataSource = dt;
    lstAssignedTo.DataTextField = "Name";
    lstAssignedTo.DataBind();
    lstAssignedTo.Items.Insert(0, "Select Onsite Tech");
}
```

Sql table is OnsiteData
columns are name and emailaddress

Form has a dropdown that sends an email.

Comment: Something not quite right here. ASP Classic and C#?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to get the email for the selected name on submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's what you want :

```
lstAssignedTo.DataSource = dt;
lstAssignedTo.DataTextField = "Name";
lstAssignedTo.DataValueField = "EmailAddress"
lstAssignedTo.DataBind();
lstAssignedTo.Items.Insert(0, "Select Onsite Tech");
```

Like this the name is displayed and you can get the corresponding email with

```
var value = lstAssignedTo.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for your help ...  I was missing the .Datavaluefield and the .selectedvalue

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your tag is misplaced. Supposing that this is ASP.NET instead of ASP-Classic and lstAssignedTo is a [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I suggest to use the [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to EmailAddress

```
lstAssignedTo.DataSource = dt;
lstAssignedTo.DataTextField = "Name";
lstAssignedTo.DataValueField = "EMailAddress";
lstAssignedTo.DataBind();
```

when needed you could extract the email address for the selected user reading the Value property

```
if(lstAssignedTo.SelectedValue != null)
{
    string email = lstAssignedTo.SelectedValue.ToString();
    ......
}
```